# When using toggle on my checkout sections, they fold up then fold back down. Should only fold up once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When using toggle on my checkout sections, they fold up then fold back down. Should only fold up once.

I've made a test case in jsfiddle: (not done with styling, so dont worry!)
http://jsfiddle.net/Wd8Ty/

The code that does it, I believe, is from AMLRWDCustom.js:

```
$('.checkoutsteptitle').addClass('down').next('.checkoutstep').fadeIn()
$('.checkoutsteptitle').on('click', function () {
    $("select, input:checkbox, input:radio, input:file").css('display', 'block');
    $(this).toggleClass('down').next('.checkoutstep').slideToggle()
});
```

I just need it to fold up once, then fold down again if clicked. That's all. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say it's likely the logic inside of slideToggle(). Can you add that here (or to your js fiddle)?

Comment: @dudewad slideToggle() is part of jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

Two of my JS files had the slideToggle() JS that I posted above. I had mistakenly copied it. Thus, it was firing twice.